# To understand how Gram-Schmidt Process is translated into this piece of code as the implementation

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, linear-algebra

Trying to understand Gram-Schmidt process from this explanation:

http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Gram-Schmidt_Process

The steps of the calculation make sense to me. However the Python implementation included in the same article doesn't seem to be aligned.

```
def normalize(v):
    return v / np.sqrt(v.dot(v))

n = len(A)

A[:, 0] = normalize(A[:, 0])

for i in range(1, n):
    Ai = A[:, i]
    for j in range(0, i):
        Aj = A[:, j]
        t = Ai.dot(Aj)
        Ai = Ai - t * Aj
    A[:, i] = normalize(Ai)
```

From above code, we see it does **dot product** for V1 and b, however the (V1,V1) part is not done as the denominator (refer to below equation). I wonder how below equation is translated into code residing in the for loop?

[image]

Comment: The second term involves the dot product of `b` with the *unit vector* of `v1`. In the code snippet this is done ahead of time with `normalize()`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I kinda understand what you mean but I can't map the  2nd term to the code hence the question. How is normalize() presented in the 2nd term?

Comment: `b` is the initial value of `Ai`. `v[1] ... v[n-1]` in the expression for `v[n]` are the values of `Aj`. `t` is the fraction term.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks a lot. what i am having difficulty to understand is t, as dot product of Ai and Aj only implements V1@B, which is the numerator of the fraction. The denominator of the fraction is missing. Seems to me normalize() may have something to do with it but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the code does exactly

[image]

Basically it normalize the previous vector (column in A) and project the current one to it and to be subtracted by the current one.

Normalization happens with every vector for neat calculation.

The V2 equation above doesn't normalize the previous vector hence the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this vectorized implementation.

Also I would suggest to go through David C lay book for theory.

```
def replace_zero(array): 
    
    for i in range(len(array)) :
        if array[i] == 0 : 
            array[i] = 1
    return array
```

```
def gram_schmidt(self,A, norm=True, row_vect=False):
        """Orthonormalizes vectors by gram-schmidt process

        Parameters
        -----------
        A : ndarray,
        Matrix having vectors in its columns

        norm : bool,
        Do you need Normalized vectors?

        row_vect: bool,
        Does Matrix A has vectors in its rows?

        Returns
        -------
        G : ndarray,
        Matrix of orthogonal vectors
        
        Gram-Schmidt Process
        --------------------
        The Gram–Schmidt process is a simple algorithm for 
        producing an orthogonal or orthonormal basis for any 
        nonzero subspace of Rn.

        Given a basis {x1,....,xp} for a nonzero subspace W of Rn,
        define

        v1 = x1
        v2 = x2 - (x2.v1/v1.v1) * v1
        v3 = x3 - (x3.v1/v1.v1) * v1  - (x3.v2/v2.v2) * v2
         .
         .
         .
        vp = xp - (xp.v1/v1.v1) * v1  - (xp.v2/v2.v2) * v2 - ....... 
             .... - (xp.v(p-1) / v(p-1).v(p-1) ) * v(p-1)


        Then {v1,.....,vp} is an orthogonal basis for W .
        In addition,
        Span {v1,.....,vp} = Span {x1,.....,xp}    for 1 <= k <= p

        References
        ----------
        Linear Algebra and Its Applications - By David.C.Lay

        """
        if row_vect :
            # if true, transpose it to make column vector matrix
            A = A.T

        no_of_vectors = A.shape[1]
        G = A[:,0:1].copy() # copy the first vector in matrix
        # 0:1 is done to to be consistent with dimensions - [[1,2,3]]

        # iterate from 2nd vector to number of vectors
        for i in range(1,no_of_vectors):

            # calculates weights(coefficents) for every vector in G
            numerator = A[:,i].dot(G)
            denominator = np.diag(np.dot(G.T,G)) #to get elements in diagonal
            weights = np.squeeze(numerator/denominator)

            # projected vector onto subspace G
            projected_vector = np.sum(weights * G,
                                      axis=1,
                                      keepdims=True)

            # orthogonal vector to subspace G
            orthogonalized_vector = A[:,i:i+1] - projected_vector

            # now add the orthogonal vector to our set
            G = np.hstack((G,orthogonalized_vector))

        if norm :
            # to get orthoNormal vectors (unit orthogonal vectors)
            # replace zero to 1 to deal with division by 0 if matrix has 0 vector
            # or normazalization value comes out to be zero
            G = G/self.replace_zero(np.linalg.norm(G,axis=0))

        if row_vect:
            return G.T

        return G
```

```
G = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
gram_schmidt(G)
>
array([[ 0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.40824829],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.40824829]])
```